# Boost Graph: Algorithm to traverse a tree down to single leaf

Tags: algorithm, boost, graph, traversal

Here's what I want to achieve:

- I have a fixed graph which structure is similar to a tree's roots: single head, multiple levels down, most levels have single nodes, some levels have sibling nodes. No circular branching.
- On each run, I want to traverse the graph from the head to first leaf encountered.
- On subsequent runs, I want to traverse again but using an alternating branch at each level. Branch toggling occurs from top first then propagates down.
- At each level I want to perform an action on the nodes hit by the traversal. No action modifies the graph.

I could do that from scratch but I think Boost Graph is most likely my best friend here. But there are so many different structures and algorithms with names only experts understand.

Do you know if what I want to do (here above) already exists in Boost Graph?

Comment: *"I want to traverse again but using an alternating branch at each level"*: what do you mean with *at each level*? Surely when at the first level you choose a different branch, the other level's branches *cannot* be the same as in a previous traversal...

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements seem contradictory:

> - On each run, I want to traverse the graph from the head to first
>   leaf encountered.

This is exactly typical for depth-first traversal (DFS)

> - On subsequent runs, I want to traverse again but using an
>   alternating branch at each level. Branch toggling occurs from top
>   first then propagates down.

This is typical of breadth-first traversal (BFS)

I can show you standard BFS/DFS with Boost,but if you want your own hybrid algorithm you'll probably have to write it yourself. My guess is that you actually want BFS¹

### Code

> - I have a fixed graph which structure is similar to a tree's roots: single head, multiple levels down, most levels have single nodes, some levels have sibling nodes. No circular branching.

```
auto make_graph() {
    enum { root, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j };
    boost::adjacency_list<> graph(j+1);
    add_edge(root, a, graph);
    add_edge(root, b, graph);
    add_edge(root, c, graph);
    add_edge(a,    d, graph);
    add_edge(a,    e, graph);
    add_edge(d,    f, graph);
    add_edge(b,    h, graph);
    add_edge(h,    i, graph);
    add_edge(i,    j, graph);
    return graph;
}
```

That corresponds to [image]

### Do The Traversal:

The simplest BFS would be:

```
int main() {
    Graph const graph = make_graph();

    boost::default_bfs_visitor vis;

    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(graph));
    boost::breadth_first_visit(graph, Vertex{ root },
        boost::visitor(vis).color_map(colors.data()));
}
```

This uses the default visitor, and it effectively does nothing.

You can override any of the events, e.g.:

```
struct Vis : boost::default_bfs_visitor {
    void discover_vertex(Vertex u, Graph const&) {
        std::cout << "Discover " << names[u] << "\n";
    }
    void examine_vertex(Vertex u, Graph const& g) {
        if (0 == out_degree(u, g)) {
            std::cout << "Examine Leaf Node " << names[u] << "\n";
        }
    }
    using Edge = Graph::edge_descriptor;
    void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph const& g) const {
        auto a = source(e, g);
        auto b = target(e, g);
        std::cout << "Tree edge " << names[a] << " -> " << names[b] << "\n";
    }
} vis;
```

Which, when all enabled, will print:

```
Discover root
Tree edge root -> a
Discover a
Tree edge root -> b
Discover b
Tree edge root -> c
Discover c
Tree edge a -> d
Discover d
Tree edge a -> e
Discover e
Tree edge b -> h
Discover h
Examine Leaf Node c
Tree edge d -> f
Discover f
Examine Leaf Node e
Tree edge h -> i
Discover i
Examine Leaf Node f
Tree edge i -> j
Discover j
Examine Leaf Node j
```

The full documentation of the events is here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/BFSVisitor.html

[image]

---

¹ (because even then the first leaf will still be reported first, the fact that it visits other nodes underway may not be observable)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a deeper look, now that I have some hints at what to look for.